# Authentication error during acess WCF service through IIS 5

Tags: wcf, hosting, wcf-security, wcf-client, iis-5

I have hosted a WCF service in my local machine(XP SP3) lets name as PushService, I am consuming this service in PushServiceClient. When I keep PushService project in running mode and try to push data from PushServiceClient I am able to Push the Data(DB is in another machine). When I stop PushService project in VS 2010 and Consume PushService hosted through IIS then I am not able to Push the Data.I am facing Authentication error during connect to DB. I am not getting where its going wrong.

IIS Version: 5.0 
Permission in IIS : Anonymous Acess
Binding: WSHttpBinding(Tried Basic http also)
Security mode: None

Thanks in advance,
Manjunath

Comment: What do you mean by stopping PushService? If you stop the service it becomes inaccessible and so your client will not be able to push data. The solution is keep the service running.

Comment: Means when I stop the PushService running in project mode, and cumsume same service through IIS then I am not able to push data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to lack of Permisswion to acess the DB, If using IIS 5.1 then in coding set it to take Default credentials if its in IIS 6.0 (Windows server 2003) set it to take local Identity in IIS AppPool. I will get back with full details on it.

Thanks Guys for your reply.
Manjunath

Answer (score 1):

Does IIS worker process have permission for database access? Impersonating the host would solve your problem.

Comment: I have tried by Impersanating the user in Web config file of service but the result is same., is there anything else I am mising of?..